# Rendering of backbone.js view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to make a simple application using backbone.js to learn the concepts of this library, but I'm having some difficulty rendering the view> I followed the tutorials but it does not work.

Below is the code of the view. I would like to put the content in element named as #tasks, but when I put it in the console instanceOfView.el, it returns undefined. Shouldn't it return the element with the content and put in html?

```
var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({

el :"#tasks",

initialize : function(){
    console.log("View created");
    this.render();
},

render : function (){
     this.$el.html("ID :" + this.model.get("id") + "Task : " + this.model.get("title"));
     return this;
}
```

})

Comment: Are you initializing your view anywhere?

Comment: Yes, in my file I created this object, view = TodoView({model : t1})

Comment: Seems fine, have a look at this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/kiyeheci/1/edit). Perhaps you can include more of your markup/code.

Comment: What was the issue? If it was just a type then the question should probably be closed, if not then consider posting your solution and accepting it.